# Scala case class prohibits call-by-name parameters?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, callbyname

**Scenario:**
I want to implement an infinite list:

```
abstract class MyList[+T]
case object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing]
case class MyNode[T](h:T,t: => MyList[T]) extends MyList[T]

//error: `val' parameters may not be call-by-name
```

**Problem:**
The error is that `call-by-name` is not allowed.

I've heard that it is because `val` or `var` constructor parameter is not allowed for `call-by-name`. For example:

```
class A(val x: =>Int) 
//error: `val' parameters may not be call-by-name
```

But in contrast the normal constructor parameter is still `val`, despite `private`.  For example:

```
class A(x: =>Int) 
// pass
```

---

So the **Question** :

- Is the problem really about `val` or `var` ?

  - If that, since the point for `call-by-name` is to defer computation. Why could not `val` or `var` computation(or initialization) be deferred?
- How to get around the `case class` limitation to implement an infinite list?

Comment: For an infinite data structure, what value does the case class sugar provide? `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` won't work. And I'm not sure what I'd expect from `unapply`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no contradiction: `class A(x: => Int)` is equivalent to `class A(private[this] val x: => Int)` and not `class A(private val x: => Int)`. `private[this]` marks a value instance-private, while a private-modifier without further specification allows accessing the value from any instance of that class.

Unfortunately, defining a `case class A(private[this] val x: => Int)` is not allowed either. I assume it is because case-classes need access to the constructor values of other instances, because they implement the `equals` method.

Nevertheless, you could implement the features that a case class would provide manually:

```
abstract class MyList[+T]

class MyNode[T](val h: T, t: => MyList[T]) extends MyList[T]{

  def getT = t // we need to be able to access t 

  /* EDIT: Actually, this will also lead to an infinite recursion
  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match{
    case MyNode(i, y) if (getT == y) && (h == i) => true
    case _ => false
  }*/

  override def hashCode = h.hashCode

  override def toString = "MyNode[" + h + "]"

}

object MyNode {
  def apply[T](h: T, t: => MyList[T]) = new MyNode(h, t)
  def unapply[T](n: MyNode[T]) = Some(n.h -> n.getT)
}
```

To check this code, you could try:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  lazy val first: MyNode[String] = MyNode("hello", second)
  lazy val second: MyNode[String] = MyNode("world", first)
  println(first)
  println(second)
  first match {
    case MyNode("hello", s) => println("the second node is " + s)
    case _ => println("false")
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I do not know for sure why call-by-name val and var members are prohibited. However, there is at least one danger to it: Think about how case-classes implement `toString`; The `toString`-method of every constructor value is called. This could (and in this example would) lead to the values calling themselves infinitely. You can check this by adding `t.toString` to `MyNode`'s `toString`-method.

**Edit:** After reading Chris Martin's comment: The implementation of `equals` will also pose a problem that is probably more severe than the implementation of `toString` (which is mostly used for debugging) and `hashCode` (which will only lead to higher collision rates if you can't take the parameter into account). You have to think carefully about how you would implement `equals` to be meaningfull.

Comment: I think you'd just leave `equals` the way it was, with the caveat that it will only work for terminating lists. That's how `Stream` works, right? `Stream(1) == Stream(1)` is `true`, but `Stream.from(1) == Stream.from(1)` doesn't halt.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Depends on how the list is used (without cycles, it is fine), but I'd probably implement a safer `equals`-method. One could for example pass a set of already visited `MyList` instances to a specialized `equalsMyList(other: MyList[T], visited: Set[MyList[T]])`-method. The specialized method could then check for recursion by checking whether `this` is already contained in `visited`, and return true in this case. The abortion criterion would probably need to check for **object identity** instead of regular equality, or we might run into the next endless recursion.

Answer (score 7):

I have also not found why exactly by-name parameters are prohibited in case classes. I guess explanation should be quite elaborate and complex.
But Runar Bjarnason in his book "[Functional Programming in Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290653)" provides a good approach to handle this obstacle. He uses the concept of a "thunk" together with memoizing.
Here is an example of Stream implementation:

```
sealed trait Stream[+A]
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]
object Stream {
 def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
  lazy val head = hd
  lazy val tail = tl
  Cons(() => head, () => tail)
 }
 def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty
 def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
  if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
 }
}
```

As you see, instead of a regular by-name parameter for the case class data constructor they use what they call a "thunk", a function of zero-arguments `() => T`. Then to make this transparent for the user they declare a smart constructor in the companion object which allows you to provide a by-name parameters and make them memoized.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually similar approach to the `Stream` solution but simplified to what is actually required:

```
case class A(x: () => Int) {
  lazy val xx = x()
}
```

So you can use your case class as:

```
def heavyOperation: Int = ???
val myA = A(heavyOperation)
val myOtherA = A(() => 10)
val useA = myA.xx + myOtherA.xx
```

Like this the actual heavy operation will be performed only when you use `xx`, i.e., only on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I like using an implicit function to make a thunk work like a call by name.

e.g. in this example:

```
case class Timed[R](protected val block: () => R) {
    override def toString() = s"Elapsed time: $elapsedTime"

    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block() // execute thunk
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    val elapsedTime = t1 - t0
  }

  implicit def blockToThunk[R](bl: => R) = () => bl //helps to call Timed without the thunk syntax
```

this let's you call Timed({Thread.sleep(1000); println("hello")}) for example with call by name syntax