# Why thunks must be explicitly forced when you define Streams iin Scala?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, thunk

I am reading a Scala textbook regarding Streams

```
sealed trait Stream[+A]
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]
```

The textbook reads

> "Due to *technical limitations*, these are thunks that must be
>   explicitly forced, rather than by-name parameters. "

I suppose the textbook means that `h: ()=>A, t: ()=>Stream[A]` should not be replaced with  `h: =>A, t: =>Stream[A]`. But what are the so-called "technical limitations" that prohibit this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what are the so-called "technical limitations" that prohibit this?

The technical limitations is that currently (as of Scala 2.12.x), Scala doesn't support `lazy val` parameters or by name parameters on *case classes*.

Why? Due to the fact that case classes get automatic method implementations derived for them by the compiler, such as `equals` and `hashCode`, for example, which are computed off of the case classes *values*. How would one compute a hashCode value, for say, an infinite stream?

A fuller answer on why case classes can't have by name parameters can be found at [Scala case class prohibits call-by-name parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749571/scala-case-class-prohibits-call-by-name-parameters)